# missing class android.permission.FOREGOUND_SERVICE in Android Cordova app causes crash on load

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get an app to run with a background plugin installed, but every time it runs on a phone, it dies, complaining that the class `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` is missing.

I've tried with API versions 31/32/33/34 and the same error message happens in all.

This same issue happens with a number of similar Cordova plugins, so I don't think it's the plugin itself.

`android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE` seems pretty basic to me - is there something I can add to the Cordova `config.xml` which will remind the compiler that it needs a copy of the class?

Here's the error message, pulled from `adb logcat`:

```
08-23 11:30:21.529 28849 28849 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.xxxxx.app2, PID: 28849
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE package com.xxxxx.app2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~zp95Q-GplocZ3hovWWes8w==/com.xxxxx.app2-oMp7W0f6NGLjWSp5mW_CBw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zp95Q-GplocZ3hovWWes8w==/com.xxxxx.app2-oMp7W0f6NGLjWSp5mW_CBw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~zp95Q-GplocZ3hovWWes8w==/com.xxxxx.app2-oMp7W0f6NGLjWSp5mW_CBw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1520)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1444)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7187)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2288)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8381)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~zp95Q-GplocZ3hovWWes8w==/com.xxxxx.app2-oMp7W0f6NGLjWSp5mW_CBw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~zp95Q-GplocZ3hovWWes8w==/com.xxxxx.app2-oMp7W0f6NGLjWSp5mW_CBw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~zp95Q-GplocZ3hovWWes8w==/com.xxxxx.app2-oMp7W0f6NGLjWSp5mW_CBw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1251)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1512)
08-23 11:30:21.532 28849 28849 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more
```

I have checked and there are very few similar reported issues online:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Didn%27t+find+class+android.permission%22 and none of them report a cause or solution.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be caused by bad caching in the build system somewhere.

To solve, I had to `cordova clean`, `cordova platform remove android`, remove any plugins that might possibly use the permission, grep for any remaining mentions of FOREGROUND_SERVICE anywhere and figure out what could be causing them, then eventually just reverse the process - add the plugins back in, add the Android platform back in, and recompile.

I think that happened is that there was something which led the build system to believe it already had the Java class included, so when I added a plugin that needed it, it *didn't add it* because it thought it was already there.

To be perfectly clear, `cordova clean` was not enough - I had to nuke this thing practically to the ground and rebuild it.